# Dealing with extremely negative comments

Tags: discussion, comments

What should I do if I post a question/answer and I get comments as if I threw it to the wolves?

Comment: If they are negative (as opposed to rude) then try to answer any concerns they have. If they are excessively rude then flag them

Comment: Sometimes despite seeming negative, they do indeed have a point. If they are just attacking you, flag as "not constructive" or "rude/offensive".

Comment: have you got any examples?

Comment: Flag them as "not constructive" or "rude/offensive".

Comment: Links. Or it didn't happen.

Comment: @mehow, not really...

Comment: @mehow ... but I had seen questions from others which, in my opinion, were given comments that are witty but unconstructive for the question (perhaps they may be taken as constructive just for being witty), and perhaps verging on offensive for some. Unfortunately, these posts were read during regular use and I cannot find them now... I guess this is common experience. Even so, I thought it was useful to know what are the options for this and other related cases (yes, an example would certainly help).

Comment: Does this help clarifying? Is an example mandatory? Should I move this to the question? Please advise.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Respond kindly to constructive comments and try to improve your questions according to them.

Very often you get asked for clarification right after posting a question. Stay put, answer to them and provide info in your question.

You can also flag inappropriate or unconstructive comments.